# Django Rest Framework serializer nested objects internal server error 500

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have three models like those:

```
class Ambulance(models.Model):
    ambulance_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ambulance_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    forms = models.ManyToManyField(Form)

class Form(models.Model):
    form_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    form_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Page(models.Model):
    page_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    page_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Untitled Page')
    form = models.ForeignKey(
        Form,
        related_name='pages',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
```

And the serializers as follow:

```
class AmbulanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    forms = FormSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Ambulance
        fields = ['ambulance_id', 'ambulance_name', 'forms']


class FormSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    pages = PageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Form
        fields = ['form_id', 'form_title', 'pages']


class PageSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = '__all__'
```

They were working and give me the nested object that I wanted but after adding many-to-many relationships, it gives me an internal server error 500 and it didn't tell me what the problem was, after debugging I found the problem occurs when calling `AmbulanceSerializer(ambulance)` or `FormSerializer(form)`

Could someone give me some hint? and what the problem actually!

Comment: What kind of request are you sending? Is it GET, POST, etc.?
Have you tried ordering your serializers?

Comment: I use it in all types of requests GET, POST, PUT, which is used to convert Django Model to JSON to send it to frontend

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong:

Can you please check this line?

```
fields = fields = ['ambulance_id', 'ambulance_name', 'forms']
```

which is wrong syntax.

You can try with this:

```
 fields = ['ambulance_id', 'ambulance_name', 'forms']
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo here, my code is good, it was working before adding many to many relationships correctly and I don't understand the problem because it gives me an internal server error and didn't tell me anything about the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Following your comment, where you state that you are using these serializers for "all types of requests", the answer is simple: remove `read_only=True` whenever you are using a nested serializer.
The `read_only` parameter will stop writes i.e. `POST`, `PUT`, etc... requests.

Comment: Thanks, I actually solved this problem by enabling the debug option and I found the error in my code, ```read_only=True``` is OK